# Spent $99 towards an "eyecare" club. Was it an HSA eligible expense?

Tags: united-states, hsa

I spent $99 at America's Best for their "eyecare club" several months ago. Through the program, one gets unlimited eye exams for the next 3 years and discounts on glasses/lenses. I figured this would've been an eligible expense, but I've been reading up on the rules and am now learning that health care clubs aren't eligible, even though I've only used it for the eye exam. Is this considered a a health club, or is it okay because it only covers eye exams?

If it's not HSA eligible, would this be considered a mistaken contribution?

Comment: Is this the United States?  Because if it's really some other jurisdiction, you might get incorrect advice.  Or you may be missing some people who may only read US questions.  In general, questions with tax implications should have a country tag.

Comment: Health club in the context of US healthcare laws generally refers to a gym or sports club.

Answer (score 4):

It's HSA eligible. It doesn't matter that they call it a "club", that's just their marketing. What you are paying for with your $99 are eye exams and glasses/lenses. So this is an HSA eligible expense.

Comment: David - isn't this a "paid in advance" situation? Can cost be paid this year for service over next 3?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I don't think it's a paid in advance situation. You aren't paying for a specific exam or a specific pair of glasses you'll get next year or getting a certain amount of credit that you will use to pay for services next year. You are paying *now* for discounted access to future services as needed over a fixed term. That makes it more like a health insurance payment than anything else (though, of course, they'll insist it's not health insurance). (But I'm hardly an expert. I couldn't find any expert discussing this precise issue.)

Comment: (To put it another way, the pay in advance situation is when you just move money from one account to another and haven't actually bought any services yet. That's not an expense of any kind, so it can't be an HSA eligible expense. This is not that at all.)

Comment: This was NOT eligible for me. I submitted this exact charge for this same plan to my FSA account and was declined. I understand that FSA is not the same as HSA but I believe the approved list of deductions is the same.